# How to Upload Excel file and convert that to Google spreadsheet programmatically?

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am writing desktop program to interact with `Google spreadsheets` and for that I need to upload `excel sheet` and convert it `Google spreadsheet` by programmatically. I checked Google drive and Google spread sheet API's could not find way to do this. If someone can any one suggest way to do this it would be grate help.

This is code I have now, which is uploading excel file correctly but it does not converted to Google spread sheet.

```
            Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
            body.Title = "My document";
            body.Description = "A test document";
            body.MimeType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("test.xlsx");
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
            request.Convert = true;
            request.Upload();

            Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to covert Word docs to a Google Doc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180602/is-it-possible-to-covert-word-docs-to-a-google-doc)

Comment: If that doesn't help you will need to post the code you are currently using to upload to Google drive.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Drive API, below is a snippet of code I used to convert an XLS File

```
function convert(xlsxFileId, name) { 
  var xlsxBlob = xlsxFileId;
  var file = {
    title: name,
    //Which Drive Folder do you want the file to be placed in
    parents: [{'id':'FOLDER_ID'}],
    key: 'XXXX',
    value: 'XXXX',
    visibility: 'PRIVATE'
  };

  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, xlsxBlob, {
    convert: true
  });
}
```

Comment: is this goole app Script?

Comment: Yes it is but **Drive** is an extended service that must be activated for that project. Go to resource menu in the script editor and follow instructions.

Comment: Thank you for the comments ,I need to do the conversion  from the client  using C#